# IOS Image Constraints not working properly in devices

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I am new to IOS and learning to work with Constraints, I basically have a TableView and an Image that I want to take up the full width of the TableView. The Image works correctly in IOS 6s but not in IOS 7 plus emulator . How can I make my constraint work ? The image is set to scale to fill and this is how it looks . As stated before with the Constraints I am trying to get the iPhone 7 plus emulator to show the image just like the iPhone 6s . My current understanding is that when you set Trailing and Leading to each other then the image is supposed to take up the full width of the TableView .

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried deleting your height Constraint? If you have top, bottom and height constraints your constraints could possibly be conflicting if your cell isn't the right height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your table isn't constrained on each side. If you look at the line between the cells on the 7 plus it doesn't go to the right edge of the screen, but it does on the 6s. Meaning it's probably the table itself that isn't constrained.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case that you have not set the right constraints of the table view or you have changed the frame of the table view through code.